# "Your device isn't compatible with this version" Android 4.0 in Virtualbox

Tags: android, google-play, virtualbox

I have succesfully setup Android 4.0 with wifi in Virtualbox. But there is one problem: I cannot install some apps like instagram, is because I am getting a "Your device isn't compatible with this version" message, and there is no install option in google play. So does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be instagram will not work with the devices with version 4.0 update android version to the latest version..it worked for me..

Comment: I am not allowed to update. I dont think the android devices,run in virtualbox, are updatable.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of instagram requires android 4.1,4.1+ . To get it work on 4.0 you can try with some old apk's like instagram version 7.9.2 etc.